# Why does zip on a generator return just one item?

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

I tried this in Python, thinking it would give me [(1,123),(2,123)]:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35)
>>> def my_generator():
...   yield 123
...
>>> zip([1,2], my_generator())
[(1, 123)]
```

Why does zip stop after creating just one item?  Is there a Pythonic way to get what I was looking for?

Comment: Because your generator only produces one item.  I think your misunderstanding is about generators rather than `zip`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an infinite generator, like this

```
def my_generator():
    while True:
        yield 123
print zip([1,2], my_generator())
# [(1, 123), (2, 123)]
```

The better way to do this would be, using [`itertools.repeat`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat), like this

```
from itertools import repeat
print zip([1,2], repeat(123))
# [(1, 123), (2, 123)]
```

Comment: Please use the `while True:` form. It's more pythonic.

Comment: @rafgoncalves As per the [docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed), `Starting with Py2.3, the interpreter optimizes "while 1" to just a single jump. In contrast "while True" takes several more steps. While the latter is preferred for clarity, time-critical code should use the first form.` :) Anyway, I updated the answer, please check :)

Comment: Ok, there's a valid reason (just learned it). Note that it does not hold for Py3, though. The Py2.x implementations don't have None, True and False as keywords, so they actually must check the value that is assigned to that variables.